# Pass data to laravel custom validation rule

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

How can I pass some variable in a custom validation rule from the controller validator?

For example:

```
      class RegisterController extends Controller {

             $someVariableINeed = 2

             protected function validator(array $data) {
                    return Validator::make($data, [
                                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                                'someField' => ['required', new \App\Rules\CustomValidationRule]
                    ]);
                }
 .....

        }
```

And the `\App\Rules\CustomValidationRule` :

```
.....

     public function passes($attribute, $value) {
       if ($value == 1 && $someVariableINeed == 2) {
        return true
       }
       return false
     }

.....
```

I need to pass variable `$someVariableINeed` from the `RegisterController` to the `\App\Rules\CustomValidationRule`.

Something similar to how `max:255` works. I want to pass into my custom rule the `255`.

Comment: i think you can added it in custom $errors array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it as a custom validation parameter like this:

```
class CustomValidationRule extends Rule
{
    public $max;

    public function __construct($max = 255)
    {
        $this->max = $max;
    }
}
```

And you could access it in the passes method like `$this->max`

And initiate the value like this:

```
new CustomValidationRule(255)
```